# Why doesn't my div follow my cursor consistently across all browsers?

Tags: jquery

I have a circle div that follows my cursor and changes size/ color when I hover a link. I'm happy with the way my code works in Chrome, Brave and Opera browsers - it's smooth, and it remains fixed when the mouse is scrolled. In Safari and Firefox however, it's not working so well.

In safari, it's very jerky and the div lags behind the cursor, and in Firefox there is a glitch when the cursor hovers the link. (If the cursor is moved over the link quickly, the circle seems to move away very suddenly and catches up with the cursor).

Can anyone see any obvious errors in my code? I'm very new to jQuery and this is something I've pieced together from tutorials, trial & error and the help of kind people on stackoverflow.

Thanking you in advance for any help.

**Update:**
It seems to be the transition property `transition: transform 0.1s;` I added to `.circle-cursor` that is causing the glitchy behaviour in Safari and Firefox.

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ecapvukw/1/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $circle = $('.circle-cursor');
  var half_cWidth = $circle.width() / 2;
  var half_cHeight = $circle.height() / 2;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $circle.css({
      transform: 'translate(' + (e.clientX - half_cHeight) + 'px, ' + (e.clientY - half_cWidth) + 'px)'
    });
  });

  $("a").hover(
    function() {
      $("body").addClass("cursor-hover");
    },
    function() {
      $("body").removeClass("cursor-hover");
    }
  );

});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #efefef;
}

.circle-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.circle-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: width .2s, height .2s, opacity 1s, background-color .2s, -webkit-transform .2s;
  -o-transition: transform .2s, width .2s, height .2s, opacity 1s, background-color .2s;
  transition: transform .2s, width .2s, height .2s, opacity 1s, background-color .2s;
}

body.cursor-hover .circle-inner {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(237, 85, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="circle-cursor">
    <span class="circle-inner"></span>
</span>
<a href="">This is a link.</a>
```

Comment: translate3d may be faster. It can force GPU to be used so might get better performance.

Comment: Hi Garr, thank you for your comment. Yes I wondered about translate3d but I'm not sure how to add the third property. I tried this - `transform: 'translate3d(' + (e.clientX - half_cHeight) + 'px, ' + (e.clientY - half_cWidth) + 'px), + px)'` but it doesn't look right and it doesn't work - do you know how I can correct it?

Comment: can you just pass '0' as last parameter: `transform: 'translate3d(' + (e.clientX - half_cHeight) + 'px, ' + (e.clientY - half_cWidth) + 'px, 0)'

Comment: the transition is also being applied to the translation, so following the cursor is always delayed by 0.1s. You should probably only apply transition to  `width` and `height`

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some issues:

- in firefox the event looks different, clientX and clientY can only be found in 'originalEvent', so addressing them directly is faster then letting the script search the whole event for eventually nested properties
- for transform the script has more to calculate then for simple 'top' and 'left' (when no transition is needed)
- the circle width and height is 0 – when you take it from 'circle-inner' you got it and then you don't need the translate(-50%, -50%) (and the second transform)

So this is faster:

```
const half_cWidth = $('.circle-inner').width() / 2;
const half_cHeight = $('.circle-inner').height() / 2;
...
circle.css({
    'top': (e.originalEvent.clientY - half_cHeight) + 'px', 
    'left': (e.originalEvent.clientX - half_cWidth) + 'px'
});
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  var circle = $('.circle-cursor');
  const half_cWidth = $('.circle-inner').width() / 2;
  const half_cHeight = $('.circle-inner').height() / 2;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    circle.css({
      'top': (e.originalEvent.clientY - half_cHeight) + 'px',
      'left': (e.originalEvent.clientX - half_cWidth) + 'px'
    });
  });

  $("a").hover(
    function() {
      $(".circle-inner").addClass("cursor-hover");
    },
    function() {
      $(".circle-inner").removeClass("cursor-hover");
    }
  );

});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #efefef;
}

.circle-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: top .1s, left .1s;
  -o-transition: top .1s, left .1s;
  transition: top .1s, left .1s;
}

.circle-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-transition: width .2s, height .2s, opacity 1s, background-color .2s;
  -o-transition: width .2s, height .2s, opacity 1s, background-color .2s;
  transition: width .2s, height .2s, opacity 1s, background-color .2s;
}

.circle-inner.cursor-hover {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(237, 85, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="circle-cursor">
    <span class="circle-inner"></span>
</span>
<a href="">This is a link.</a>
```

If don't want to use top and left here is an working example with transform:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  const circle = $('.circle-cursor');
  const half_cWidth = $('.circle-inner').width() / 2;
  const half_cHeight = $('.circle-inner').height() / 2;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    circle.css({
      transform: 'translate(' + (e.originalEvent.clientX - half_cHeight) + 'px, ' + (e.originalEvent.clientY - half_cWidth) + 'px)'
    });
  });

  $("a").hover(
    function() {
      $("body").addClass("cursor-hover");
    },
    function() {
      $("body").removeClass("cursor-hover");
    }
  );

});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #efefef;
}

.circle-cursor {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.circle-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-transition: width .2s, height .2s, opacity 1s, background-color .2s;
  -o-transition: width .2s, height .2s, opacity 1s, background-color .2s;
  transition: width .2s, height .2s, opacity 1s, background-color .2s;
}

body.cursor-hover .circle-inner {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(237, 85, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="circle-cursor">
    <span class="circle-inner"></span>
</span>
<a href="">This is a link.</a>
```

Comment: Hi biberman, thanks for your answer. For some reason this is still really glitchy in safari when the transition I had set for the `transform` property is instead added to `top` and `left`. Here's a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v7m68n5x/

Comment: There was another bug with the circle dimensions, i fixed it in my answer. Now you don't need transform anymore and the glitch should have vanished...

Comment: translate is much more efficient than adjusting left and top, which requires laying out the DOM again.

Comment: I added transition for top and left to my answer. Please test it since i have no safari nor any apple device.

Comment: I updated my answer an added an example with translate instead of top and left. Please test in Safari since i have none...

Comment: Thanks biberman. Ideally I'd rather use transform. I've tested both in Safari and Firefox and it seems to be the transition property with the delay of 0.1s that is causing the glitch.. The one that uses transform still seems smoother than the one using left and top, but both are still affected by the transition css.